# CSS bundle minification replacing Unicode characters

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, minify

I'm seeing an issue in VS2012 that replaces the Unicode characters in my minified CSS code.

```
font-family: "FontAwesome";
content: "\f002";
```

This is fine in the un-minified bundle css file that is created, however, the \f002 is being replaced in the minified bundle css file.

```
font-family:"FontAwesome";content:"";
```

Is there some kind of escape I can use to stop this from happening?

Comment: why is that replacement a problem? Isn't the escape sequence equivalent to the character itself?

Comment: This is working as intended, 5 bytes were minified to 3

Comment: I understand its working as intended, but for some reason this stops the font loading as intended. So rather than seeing the icon as determined by the Unicode value, I'm getting random characters. So I just want to stop the minification on this small section.

Comment: @jonvines not a font problem or related to fonts at all. Declare UTF-8 as the encoding of your page

Comment: @Esailija I think you are right in the declaration of utf-8, it is not on the page that this needs to happen though, it is during the minification process. However this setting cannot be set anywhere that I can see within visual studio. This is a pretty frustrating little behaviour.

Comment: Encoding is actually set in the bundle file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bundle minify="true" runOnBuild="true">

Comment: @jonvines you need to declare encoding *as well as* encode everything physically in the encoding you declared. Right now you are just physically encoding as UTF-8 but not declaring it judging from the fact that you see many characters instead of one which is screaming UTF-8 misinterpreted as Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1

Comment: @Esailija Thanks Esailija, I have double checked the master page and it is declared as utf-8 in the header. The response headers also show utf-8 as the charset.

Comment: @jonvines and what is the content you see with UTF-8 being used as a response header? It should either work or you should see one or more of this character: `�` (Not many random characters like earlier)

Comment: @Esailija Still the random characters. I'm getting the � in VS, but on the actual page it is still the random chars. I can only assume that it is not setting the font via the font family in css. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with this. I'm happy that the minifcation is working as intended so this has answered that question.

Comment: I have a similar problem - I'm using the unicode line feed character (`\00000A`) but the minifier is changing that to '\n', which doesn't create a line break, it actually shows an 'n' in the page content.  This is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: adding `@charset 'utf-8';` to the top of your CSS may help.